# Ajax result as array and JSON.parse error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have coded an ajax request and the data is returned as an array to be used in a timepicker.

**Ajax Call:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var consultdate;
var userid;
var cat;
var timezone;
var consultstart;
var consultend;
$('#consultdate').change(function() {
consultdate = $('#consultdate').val();
userid= '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
cat = '<?php echo $category;?>';
timezone = '<?php echo $time_zone;?>';
consultstart = '<?php echo $consultation_start;?>';
consultend = '<?php echo $consultation_end;?>';
//alert(consultdate);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'user_date-time_qry.php',
cache: false,
dataType : "text",
data: {consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat, timezone : timezone, consultstart : consultstart, consultend: consultend },
success: function(data)
{
if (!$('input#consulttime').data("set")) {
alert(data);
var result = $.parseJSON(data);
$("input#consulttime").val('');
$('input#consulttime').prop("disabled", false);
$('input#consulttime').timepicker('remove').timepicker({'timeFormat': 'h:i A','disableTextInput': true, 'minTime':result[0] ,'maxTime': '<?php echo $consultation_end; ?>','step': 15,'disableTimeRanges':result[1]});
   }
},
error : function() {
alert("Error while loading data");
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

I expect var result to be an array of json encoded values, which is used in `minTime` as `result[0]`  and `disableTimeRanges` as `result[1]`

The relevant portion of user_date-time_qry.php is as follows:

**UPDATED: user_date-time_qry.php**

```
 $consultation_start = '"'.$consultation_start. '"';
    $consult_time_UTC = '['.implode(',',$consult_time_UTC).']'; 
    $prebooked_time_UTC = $consult_time_UTC ; //require format as ['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']

    echo $result = array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC);
$result = array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC);
foreach ($result as $results) {
echo $results; 
}
```

In console 
Getting value as "06:00 PM"[]
"06:00 PM" is value 1 && [] is value 2. How to get it as separate values in ajax response ?

**Update:**

Since i am unable to comprehend it, trying another solution with 2 ajax calls. Thanks for all the feedback anyway.

Comment: dont compile the json yourself, use json_encode.

Comment: look your network response check if it has an error

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I need to json encode time oicker in this format.['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']. Hence i opted for manual encode.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
echo $result = array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC);
```

to this

```
$result = array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Actually to get data in `JSON` format in `PHP` you can just store all the data in an `array` and use `json_encode` function to convert them.

Comment: But i have already data in json encoded format:
$consultation_start = '"'.$consultation_start. '"';

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
echo $result = array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC);
```

you cannot echo an `array`, instead you have to use `json_encode` like:

```
echo json_encode(array($consultation_start, $prebooked_time_UTC));
```

and do not wrap the values in quotes like:

```
'"'.$consultation_start. '"'
```

Comment: I have formated so that i need the datepicker format to be in:
['8.30 AM', '8.45 AM'], ['12:15 PM', '12:30 PM']. It was working fine without array.

Comment: cant we use foreach to echo array ??

Comment: Yes, you can. But that's not work with the ajax call

Comment: No you cannot loop, just use `json_encode` and parse it in js and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**simple way:--**

The data is coming back as the string representation of the JSON and you aren't converting it back to a JavaScript object. Set the **dataType** to just '**json**' to have it converted automatically.

> Example Like:--

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'user_date-time_qry.php',
    cache: false,
    dataType : "json",
    data: {consultdate : consultdate, userid : userid, cat : cat, timezone : timezone, consultstart : consultstart, consultend: consultend },
    success: function(data)
    {
    //ENTER CODE

    },
    error : function() {
           alert("Error while loading data");
       }

});
```

Comment: Response payload is none.

Comment: okay and using Anoter example i have enter new solution (solution title):-- Anoter example using this way

Answer (score 0):

**Anoter example using this way:--**

**user_date-time_qry.php** file all convert into **json** format using below example all array convert into **json format** using this way:--

```
<?php
         $marks = array( 
            "mohammad" => array (
               "physics" => 35,
               "maths" => 30,   
               "chemistry" => 39
            ),

            "qadir" => array (
               "physics" => 30,
               "maths" => 32,
               "chemistry" => 29
            ),

            "zara" => array (
               "physics" => 31,
               "maths" => 22,
               "chemistry" => 39
            )
         );
         echo json_encode($marks);
      ?>
```

**These respone provide (ALL DATA CONVERT INTO JSON FORMAT):--**

{"mohammad":{"physics":35,"maths":30,"chemistry":39},"qadir":{"physics":30,"maths":32,"chemistry":29},"zara":{"physics":31,"maths":22,"chemistry":39}}